# Returning array into $scope doesn't work

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, ionic-framework

I've got an array arr in a function which I'd like to return to $scope.notifications so I can use it in the HTML within the Ionic Framework.
I need to do it via a function so I can perform several actions with the array before returning it later on.
My controller:

```
.controller('notificationsCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.notifications = function(){
        var arr = [
            {user:"misterx", name:"Mister X", action:4, image: "https://www.holidaycheck.de/mediaproxy?target=hcaHR0cDovL3d3dy5ob3RlbC5kZS9tZWRpYS9ob3RlbC9waWN0dXJlcy8zMzQvMzM0MTIzL0V4dGVyaW9yXzYzNTkyNzk5NDMyODQ1OTAwMi5qcGc%3D"},
            {user:"misterx", name:"Mister X", action:2, image: "https://www.holidaycheck.de/mediaproxy?target=hcaHR0cDovL3d3dy5ob3RlbC5kZS9tZWRpYS9ob3RlbC9waWN0dXJlcy8zMzQvMzM0MTIzL0V4dGVyaW9yXzYzNTkyNzk5NDMyODQ1OTAwMi5qcGc%3D"},
            {user:"ladyx", name:"Lady X", action:1}
        ];
        return arr;
    }
})
```

The HTML:

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="msg in notifications" class="item-text-wrap">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-80">
            <strong>{{msg.name}}</strong> (<em>@{{msg.user}}</em>) {{msg.action}}.
        </div>
        <div class="col-20">
            <img src="{{msg.image}}" style="border-radius: 50px; width: 100%">
        </div>
    </div>
</ion-item>
```

When I pass notifications directly as an array, without a function, it works. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What do you mean by "perform several actions with the array before returning it later on"? It seems unnecessary to me to use a function here.

Answer (score 2):

Using `ng-repeat="msg in notifications"` tries to repeat over the function itself, not its return value.  You want to call the function instead:

`<ion-item ng-repeat="msg in notifications()">`

https://jsfiddle.net/dj1gpjb8/

I should point out, though, that there are performance issues with this approach: the function will be called frequently because Angular can't predict whether the result of the function will change.  You're better off embedding notifications as a plain array on the scope; anything that modifies that array later will automatically trigger the component to re-render with the new value(s):

```
  $scope.notifications = [{
    user: "misterx",
    name: "Mister X",
    //...
  }];

  $scope.addNotification = function() {
    $scope.notifications.unshift({
      user: "newguy",
      name: "New Guy"
    });
    // angular will notice that notifications[] has changed, and re-render the component on the next $digest
  };
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1du593af/

Answer (score -2):

The following code is current so no need to use function to return JSON format

```
.controller('notificationsCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.notifications = [
        {user:"misterx", name:"Mister X", action:4, image: "https://www.holidaycheck.de/mediaproxy?target=hcaHR0cDovL3d3dy5ob3RlbC5kZS9tZWRpYS9ob3RlbC9waWN0dXJlcy8zMzQvMzM0MTIzL0V4dGVyaW9yXzYzNTkyNzk5NDMyODQ1OTAwMi5qcGc%3D"},
        {user:"misterx", name:"Mister X", action:2, image: "https://www.holidaycheck.de/mediaproxy?target=hcaHR0cDovL3d3dy5ob3RlbC5kZS9tZWRpYS9ob3RlbC9waWN0dXJlcy8zMzQvMzM0MTIzL0V4dGVyaW9yXzYzNTkyNzk5NDMyODQ1OTAwMi5qcGc%3D"},
        {user:"ladyx", name:"Lady X", action:1}
    ];

}
```

})

Comment: They already know it works as an array, that's mentioned in the question. They want to do it as a function. That's also mentioned in the question.  (It's also a good idea to explain your answers, instead of just dumping code and saying "this works")

Comment: I know that but if you do not pass param to function there is no need to use function.

Comment: I know that too.  But that's not what they asked about. (It may very well be that they *are* passing a parameter to the function, or have other good reason to want to do it that way, but omitted that from the question as part of making a good move.)  If someone asks "I know I can do X, but why doesn't Y work", then answering "do X" without explanation is not helpful.